Is it possible to use Docker Compose watch with an image created by Earthfile?
So I have this simple code to run.
import streamlit as st 

st.title("hellobored")

I created a docker image of this code with a simple earthfile with the command earthly +all
VERSION 0.8
streamlit: 
    FROM python:3.11-slim
    WORKDIR /src/app
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
    RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip install streamlit
    COPY ./hellobored.py /src/app/hellobored.py
    RUN ls
    EXPOSE 8501
    ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "/src/app/hellobored.py", "--server.port=8501"]
    SAVE IMAGE hellobored

all: 
    BUILD +streamlit

I have a Docker Compose file that looks like this:
version: '3.8'
services:   
  streamlit:
    image: hellobored
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    develop: 
      watch:
      - path: ./
        action: rebuild
      - path: ./
        target: /src/app/
        action: sync 

I already tried using rebuild or sync separately, but both don't seem to work. I used docker compose up -d and docker compose watch to see the watch-related problem and received this error for the rebuild:

[+] Running 1/0manualy
✔ Container hellobored-streamlit-1  Running                                           0.0s
can't watch service "streamlit" with action rebuild without a build context

And this error for the sync:

[+] Running 1/0
✔ Container hellobored-streamlit-1  Running                                           0.0s
none of the selected services is configured for watch, consider setting an 'develop' section

I can't find a way to give Docker Compose a build context for Earthly on the net, so I'm asking here. For note, I need the build to be done by Earthly because the images I create are 10GB, and Earthly can compile them in seconds. I need to watch because it would be really long to rebuild and reload manually after every change.

In your initial setup, the docker-compose-watch command failed because there was no build context specified. Docker Compose requires a build context to track changes and trigger rebuilds. Without a build context, the watch command cannot determine which files to monitor for changes.
build:
  context: .


I got the answer! You just need to add a build context. Why? No idea, but it works, so I'm happy.
version: '3.8'
services:   
  streamlit:
    image: hellobored
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    develop: 
      watch:
      - path: ./
        target: /src/app/
        action: sync 


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
